# List location of executables within the CTest test suite

Tags: cmake, ctest

I have some source code that is compiled using CMake, with unit tests that are added to CTest via the CMake directive `add_test()`. I want the list of executables (absolute/relative path) that are used within this test suite.

Since tests are added as follows:

```
add_test(NAME ${A} COMMAND ${execA})
add_test(NAME ${B} COMMAND ${execB})
add_test(NAME ${C} COMMAND ${execA} ${addOptions})
```

there are only two distinct executables (`${execA}`, `${execB}`) for three tests (`${A}`, `${B}`, and `${C}`).

I am totally fine having duplicates and ignoring options or having options.

So, the ideal output would be the following (but I certainly can do some parsing manually if needed):

```
 src/folder1/test/testThisFunction
 src/folder2/test/testThatFunction
 src/folder1/test/testThisFunction -WithThisFlag
```

The closest I was able to get was with:

```
ctest -N,--show-only
```

which does not run the tests, but simply shows them:

```
    Start 1: testA
1/3 Test #1: testA .......................   Passed    0.01 sec
    Start 2: testB
2/3 Test #2: testB .......................   Passed    0.01 sec
    Start 3: testC
3/3 Test #3: testC ........................  Passed    0.01 sec
```

Unfortunately, this output does not contain the information about the path to the executable.

In this example above, it is assumed that

```
${execA} = testThisFunction
${execB} = testThatFunction
```

where `testThisFunction` and `testThatFunction` are CMake targets (unit tests) and

```
${A} = "testA"
${B} = "testB"
${C} = "testC"
${addOptions} = "-WithThisFlag"
```

store names of the tests and options, respectively.

While I have the access to *CMakeLists.txt*, I strongly prefer to do this solely on `ctest` level after CMake configuring and subsequent compilation are already completed (thus, not generating list of executables using CMake commands in *CMakeLists.txt*).

If this is relevant, I am using CTest 3.10.2, but open to upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you only need the `-N` or the `--show-only` option in the `ctest` command, not both. In your case, CTest silently ignored your command line option `-N,--show-only` because it was not recognized. The output indicates that your tests did run. To simply list them, use:

```
ctest --show-only
```

Getting to your question: If you upgrade to CMake 3.14 or higher, you gain the JSON-formatted `ctest --show-only` option.

```
ctest --show-only=json-v1
```

This will print information about each of your tests, including the arguments passed to each. Your output from this may contain something like this:

```
  "tests" :
  [
    {
      "backtrace" : 1,
      "command" :
      [
        "src/folder1/test/testThisFunction"
      ],
      "config" : "Debug",
      "name" : "testA",
      "properties" :
      [
        {
          "name" : "WORKING_DIRECTORY",
          "value" : "src"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "backtrace" : 3,
      "command" :
      [
        "src/folder2/test/testThatFunction"
      ],
      "config" : "Debug",
      "name" : "testB",
      "properties" :
      [
        {
          "name" : "WORKING_DIRECTORY",
          "value" : "src"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "backtrace" : 5,
      "command" :
      [
        "src/folder1/test/testThisFunction",
        "-WithThisFlag"
      ],
      "config" : "Debug",
      "name" : "testC",
      "properties" :
      [
        {
          "name" : "WORKING_DIRECTORY",
          "value" : "src"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

In the output, the full path to the executable and the test's command line arguments are listed after `"command" :`.

Comment: got it to work. Thanks for clarifying a problem with several options and giving the direction to json-v1. I will be able to parse it on my own now.